# Replacing Square Brackets without value in .json array/pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, brackets

I was wondering if there is a way to remove/replace null/empty square brackets in json or pandas dataframe. I have tried to replace them after converting into string via .astype(str) and it is successful and/but it seems it converts all json values into string and I can not process further with the same structure. I would appreciate any solution/recommendation. thanks...

[image]

Comment: Hi, what would you want to replace them with?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to replace them with "nan" in order to properly construct the dataframe in pandas with "concat" command. I have tried to solve the problem with different methods when I attempt to append the df lists it turns out with an error "DataFrame constructor not properly called! error." Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", [1, 2, 3], [], "d"], "col2": ["e", [], "f", "g"]})

print(df)
# Output
```

[image]

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.NA if isinstance(x, list) and not x else x)

print(df)
# Output
```

[image]

Comment: This perfectly works for the single square brackets ([ ]) but when I have got double one (like this: [[ ]]) it does not help removing/replacing them, do you have recommendation for this case, too? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Replace `and not x` with `and (not x or not any(y for y in x))`. Cheers.